# which is the exactly definition of 2-3 tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

Sorry,I can't post pictures, so I print them with keyboard.

```
                             [6:-]

               [2:4]                        [8:-]      

     [0:1]     [2:3]    [4:5]         [6:7]       [8:9]
```

this one is from 《data structure and algorithm》, it is the picture of 2-3 tree, you can see every data on father node must on their child node.

```
                             [50:90]

      [20:-]                 [70:-]                  [120:150]

[10:-]    [30:40]       [60:-]    [80:-]    [100:110]   [130:140]   [160:-]
```

and this one is from another book called《data abstraction and problem solving  with c++》, data on father node doesn't on their child node.

Which one is right?

Comment: They may both be valid. The top one allows duplicates (just places them to the right subtree). The bottom one doesn't have any duplicates, but doesn't show how duplicates are addressed. You could code a 2-3 tree to reject duplicate values, in which case the top tree would be invalid. It depends on how you decide to handle dups. Otherwise they are both valid. BTW, the definitive book on algorithms is the CLRS book, but I think they skip over 2-3 trees by calling them a special case of the B-tree, so it's not much help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I know the CLRS, but it is too difficult to me now. Now  I am watching 《data structure and algorithm》 and coding every samples and exercises on the book, but some of them are also difficult, I spent much time on it, is that a good way to learn?

Comment: Yes, coding basic data structures like trees, graphs, heaps, queues, etc, and sorting algorithms is a great way to learn. The 2-3 tree is challenging to code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both 2-3 trees, since the "2-3" just refers to the number of children each node has.  But these trees have different more specific names.

The first one, in which the parents copy keys from the children, is called a "B+ tree":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree

The second one, in which the parent keys are not copies, is called a "B tree": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree

Note the there are usually values associated with the keys, and in the B+ tree, the internal nodes don't contain values.

B+ trees are popular for database indexes backed by the file system.  Because the internal nodes don't contain values, they can have higher fan-out, reducing the height of the tree and making access faster.

Often the leaf nodes don't actually store values either -- they store pointers to the locations where the values are stored, and this conveniently gives the leaf nodes of a B+ tree exactly the same structure as the internal nodes.